# stored the several value of the textbox into an array php

Tags: php

Im making my project, and my project is make a program that will enter name,age and address.
There was a 3 textbox and a submit button. when the user answer the 3 textbox and click submit button, the data or the input of the user will save into an array, but when the user try to input again the previous input will not be replace or it will be there together with the user new inputs, and later those input where use to save into mysql db, do you think this project is possible using php array? i have no sample code because i dont know how to start.thank you so much.

**index.php**

```
<form action='index.php' method='get'>
 <input type='text' name='name[]'>
 <input type='text' name='age[]'>
 <input type='address' name='address[]'>
 <input type='submit' value='Save'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to use 'sticking form' - form elements that stick (keep) the values previously entered.

You can make a textbox sticky like this:

```
<input type='text' name='name' value='<?php isset($_POST['name'])? $_POST[\'name\']: ""; ?>' />
```

You need to sanitize the inputs, however, if you try to use it for some real application.